# How can I use specific method such as GET, POST, PUT, or DELETE in API gateway by using Amplify CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify-cli

When adding an API gateway path, by using Amplify CLI the method is always ANY, but I want to use a specific method such as GET, POST, PUT, or DELETE instead of ANY.
So, how do I use/change the path method?

Answer (score 2):

This feature isn't supported by Amplify yet, it is marked as a feature request in their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/4245) where you can follow the discussion about it:  The current workaround is to manually edit the Amplify CloudFormation template in `amplify/backend/api/<resource-name>/` to create different paths, but the changes to this file are often overwritten by the amplify cli so the solution will only be temporary.